# Extracting NCBI RefSeq and Submitted GenBank assembly accession numbers using Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, biopython

[Title: Difficulty Extracting GenBank Accession Number Using Species and Strain Name, using webscraping (Using BeautifulSoup or Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78178650/title-difficulty-extracting-genbank-accession-number-using-species-and-strain-n/78179474#78179474) Following this post, I'm attempting to extract NCBI RefSeq and Submitted GenBank assembly accession numbers from a webpage using Selenium and BeautifulSoup in Python. However, I'm encountering an issue where the previous code doesn't work for genomes with a single assembly, as it opens a different page.

To address this, I've tried a different approach:

This codes

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException

# Define the search term
search_term = "Streptomyces anthocyanicus NBC 01687"

# Open a Chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Construct the search URL for assembly
search_url = f"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/?term={search_term.replace(' ', '+')}"

# Navigate to the search URL
driver.get(search_url)

try:
    # Wait for the main content to be visible
    main_content = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "maincontent")))

    # Find the assembly information
    assembly_info = main_content.text if main_content else "Assembly information not found"
    #print(assembly_info)

    # Extract GenBank and RefSeq assembly IDs if the assembly widget is present
    try:
        assembly_table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "assembly-widget")
        rows = assembly_table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
            if len(cells) == 3:
                label = cells[1].text.strip()
                assembly_id = cells[2].text.strip()
                if label == "NCBI RefSeq assembly":
                    print("NCBI RefSeq assembly:", assembly_id)
                elif label == "Submitted GenBank assembly":
                    print("Submitted GenBank assembly:", assembly_id)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Assembly information widget not found.")

except TimeoutException:
    print("Elements not found or timed out waiting for them to appear.")

# Initialize variables to store assembly IDs
genbank_assembly = None
refseq_assembly = None

# Split the assembly information into lines and iterate over them
lines = assembly_info.split("\n")
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if "NCBI RefSeq assembly" in lines[i]:
        refseq_assembly = lines[i+1].strip()
    elif "Submitted GenBank assembly" in lines[i]:
        genbank_assembly = lines[i+1].strip()

# Print the assembly IDs if found
if refseq_assembly:
    print("NCBI RefSeq assembly:", refseq_assembly)
if genbank_assembly:
    print("Submitted GenBank assembly:", genbank_assembly)


# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

output is

```
Assembly information widget not found.
NCBI RefSeq assembly: GCF_036226945.1
Submitted GenBank assembly: GCA_036226945.1
```

However, this code opens the entire page, , so I process extract the RefSeq and GenBank accession numbers.

But,  I Think, its not good way, there will be some correct way to acheive

anotherway I found is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

# Define the search term
search_term = "Streptomyces anthocyanicus NBC 01687"

# Open a Chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    # Construct the search URL for assembly
    search_url = f"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/?term={search_term.replace(' ', '+')}"

    # Navigate to the search URL
    driver.get(search_url)

    # Find elements containing the organism name
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'NCBI RefSeq assembly')]") #{search_term}

    if elements:
        print(f"Text '{search_term}' found on the webpage.")
        # Loop through elements containing the organism name
        for element in elements:
            # Find the parent element of the matched element
            parent_element = element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..") # for sibling"following-sibling::*[1]" #for parents ".." and for grand parents "../.." 
            # Print the text content of the parent element
            print("Parent element:")
            print(parent_element.text)
            
            
    else:
        print(f"Text '{search_term}' not found on the webpage.")

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)

finally:
    # Quit the browser
    driver.quit()
```

But I want to do same way as I did previous [Title: Difficulty Extracting GenBank Accession Number Using Species and Strain Name, using webscraping (Using BeautifulSoup or Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78178650/title-difficulty-extracting-genbank-accession-number-using-species-and-strain-n/78179474#78179474) for this page, so I can collect all information in one scripts ,
Could someone please suggest me proper code to achieve this?, kindly help

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is there nothing useful in the extensive REST API / datasets they provide? E.g., if you could search by taxon then filter on strain (Modifier): https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets/genome/?taxon=68174 ; reports: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets/docs/v2/reference-docs/data-reports/genome-assembly/

Comment: @QHarr Thank you for your comment, is it possible to download that table

Comment: 1/3 You could scrape. I would get a free API key and focus on [this endpoint](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets/docs/v2/reference-docs/rest-api/#post-/genome/dataset_report) initially as mirrors that table. Then look for any suitable endpoints supporting batch if that is more appropriate to the volume of planned requests

Comment: 2/3 that page POSTs with body, incl your desired filtering, as `{"page_size":100,"page_token":"","returned_content":"COMPLETE","sort":[],"taxons":["68174"],"filters":{"has_annotation":"True","assembly_source":"all","search_text":["NBC 01687"],"assembly_version":"current","exclude_paired_reports":"True"}}` though booleans are likely unquoted

Comment: 3/3 you can also right-click the table and in dev tools elements tab copy the table element outerHTML and paste into CSV/Excel. You'd need to tidy rows a little

Comment: @QHarr, thank u, u gave me new idea, and it's useful, I have lots of data with me, and I wanted to scrap all information or desired information, unfortunately I don't have accession number, so I was trying to scrap using Species id, but I faced problm because for different different pages will for different species, n I kept working since weeks, n finally I did, I made scripts which will handle different pages, kindly suggest if any other way also, which will help me to automate the scraping, since everytime I m getting this kindvof work, it's troubling me doing manually

Comment: @QHarr I followed your suggestion and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code, simplified it, and came up with this working code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# Define the search term
search_term = "Streptomyces anthocyanicus NBC 01687"

# Open a Chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Construct the search URL for assembly
search_url = f"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/?term={search_term.replace(' ', '+')}"

# Navigate to the search URL
driver.get(search_url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Extract GenBank and RefSeq assembly IDs if the assembly widget is present
try:
    refseq_assembly = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//dt[text()='NCBI RefSeq assembly']//following::dd/span"))).text
    print("NCBI RefSeq assembly:", refseq_assembly)
    genbank_assembly = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//dt[text()='Submitted GenBank assembly']//following::dd/span"))).text
    print("Submitted GenBank assembly:", genbank_assembly)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Elements not found or timed out waiting for them to appear.")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

and it prints

```
NCBI RefSeq assembly: GCF_036226945.1      
Submitted GenBank assembly: GCA_036226945.1
```

Comment: If there's some concern that only one of the two assembly codes might exist, you can separate the `try` into two and print whatever is available.